# Can I install Windows onto the SSD part of my fusion drive, overwriting Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, windows-8.1, boot-camp, fusion-drive

I have a Mac Mini with a fusion drive (128GB SSD + 1TB 5400RPM HDD).

Running Windows on a 5400RPM Hard Drive (with boot camp) is a bit annoying, so if I'm not intending on using OS X for a while can I install Windows onto the SSD instead, and then safely go back to OS X (with a fresh OS X install) in the future or will this break my Mac?

It looks easy enough in the Windows installer (it can see the SSD etc) but I'm apprehensive to go ahead so thought I would ask here first.

Thanks

Comment: Hmm. I don't see a reason why it would not be possible. But can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend being entirely sure this is what you want to do before starting out.

Windows cannot use the 'Fusion' aspect of a Fusion Drive - it doesn't understand the technology.

You can install Windows via Boot Camp, preserving the Mac functionality, but it will not use any part of the SSD, only the HD.

Any attempt to alter any partitioning from within Windows will 'break' the drive, as Windows does not see exactly what Boot Camp does to the drive in order to install Windows.

You can manually break the Fusion Drive down into 2 separate drives, SSD & HD & install Windows on the SSD.
This will, of course, destroy any data already on the drive & possibly leave you struggling to boot the machine into anything at all, trying to get Windows onto it.

Make sure you have bootable Windows and Mac USB keys before attempting anything.

In order to get Mac OS back onto the drive at any later stage you would need to start up from Internet Recovery [Cmd/R at the chimes] & rebuild from scratch, or boot to your existing USB key with Mac OS install on it.

Comment: Would Windows have problems booting from the SSD?

Comment: So basically, *here be dragons*? Cool, I'll give this a shot later and report back with an answer.

Comment: I'm not certain, tbh, but I've seen too many tales of woe where people have 'broken' their drives trying to do things like this. Personally, I have my Boot Camp on a totally separate drive & my main Mac boot drive fastidiously backed up & also cloned to a known-good bootable drive, which lives in a box for emergencies. Belt & braces. I also have an old-style Mac Pro so I have 6 drives in here, with easy swap, & a box full of spare drives. This is the kind of task I would test on spares before going anywhere near my main setup.

Comment: Yes - *here be dragons* indeed. You can always get back to ground zero from Internet Recovery - but you may end up having to do some nasty single-user or terminal stuff to rebuild the fusion drive. Look up posts by [klanomath](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/93229/klanomath) on Ask Different for the full skinny on rebuilding them.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, much appreciated! Just to add, this isn't my primary computer anyway, I got it to play around with.

Comment: A late thought - I'm really not sure Windows would know how to boot a Mac *without* Boot Camp. Otherwise, what would we have Boot Camp for in the first place? Dragons await the unwary ;)